# Reorganise PHP array

Tags: php

I have a function that collects data from a `csv` file and inserts it into an array.

Here is how my data looks like, when I display the contents of the array:

```
23,cars     ,43 063
23,houses   ,17 306
23,shops    ,13 300
23,garages  ,13 094
23,hotels   ,10 025
22,cars     ,75 675
22,houses   ,40 403
22,shops    ,32 243
22,garages  ,30 649
22,hotels   ,29 734
```

So what what I want to do now is to modify the above array in order to obtain something like this in `PHP`:

```
cars,   43 063,75 675
houses, 17 306,40 403
shops,  13 300,32 243
garages,13 094,30 649
hotels, 10 025,29 734
```

Comment: From where did `75 675` came from in cars? Any logic?

Comment: Mr. Alien, look at the top array, it has multiple 'cars' entries. The resulting array combines all the values.

Comment: Aaaaa got that, but again, he will need , I guess

Comment: Is the first block of code an array? If so could you post a print_r or var_dump of it so we can see the key=>value pairs?

Comment: The results from the block are contents of my csv file

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to your first data dump. I'm assuming it's structured as:

```
$data = array (
    23 => array(
        'cars' => 43063,
        'houses' => 17306,
        'shops' => 13300,
        'garages' => 13094,
        'hotels' => 10025
    ),
    22 => array(
        'cars' => 75675,
        'houses' => 40403,
        'shops' => 32243,
        'garages' => 30649,
        'hotels' => 29734
    )
);
```

If this is the case, I would suggest the following code:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($data as $entries){
    foreach ($entries as $index => $value){
        $newArray[$index][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now you will have $newArray, which contains all the indexes with their respective values.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Fyntasia, this is what i was looking for, but it's not giving me the desired results because myarray is not structured in the way like the one you are showing in the example. Here is an example of my array `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿23
            [1] => cars 24
            [2] => 43 063
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => cars
            [2] => 17 306
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => houses
            [2] => 13 300
        )

        )`

Comment: Great, you can edit the code to suit your array format. Good luck!